# Overlaying a png image over a HTML page iOS

Tags: html, ios, css

I have a HTML page which I have created a set of instructions for in a form of a png image. The image appears when the user first access the page but as soon as they click the page the instructions disappears which is exactly how I want it to work. It works fine in safari, however When I am trying to load in onto my iPhone the div in which the png image is in appears but the actual PNG file does not. Any ideas what I am doing wrong or what I have missed? Any help would be much appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div id="overlay">
 <img src="./instructions.png" width="300" height="480" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#overlay {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
position:absolute;
z-index: 10;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How big is the png (in pixels)? iOS devices have a limit as to how big the files can be, to load them in. http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-javascript-ios-maximum-image-size/

Comment: W:300px H:425px is that why it isn't showing maybe?

Comment: Oh, that does seem pretty small, so probably not. If you switch out the image for one with a smaller file size, does it work? Or have you tried removing the period before /instructions.png? I've never seen that done before, so it may not be valid...?

Comment: Nope unfortunately that still doesn't change anything. I can see the div there as I have dropped the opacity on it and when I click it, it disappears but the png file just wont display in the div.

Comment: Hmm, welll.. Could you try making a js fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net)? If you reduce it to just the code that has the problems (ie take out all html/css etc that doesn't relate to the problem), it could help to show where the problem lies.